# Rails JSON non-standard characters

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a string within my database that contains this sample substring.

```
string = "\357\277\275\357\277\275"
```

When I try to convert this to JSON, I get a lot of these bad boys (since they are non-ASCII characters).

```
�
```

Then, when jQuery tries to parse the JSON, it just craps out and gives me a `SyntaxError: Unexpected Token`

Here are three possible solutions.

1. Convert the string into JSON acceptable values
2. Remove the offending characters
3. Replace the string with a message such as "Invalid Characters"

I am fine with any of these, but don't know how to go about them. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to strip unprintable characters from strings in Ruby, you can use the following regex.

```
"your_string".gsub!(/[^[:print:]]/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

`"\357\277\275"` is the ascii octal representation of the Replacement Character(�).  This indicates that when you converted to JSON there were non-ascii characters in your string.  Ideally, you would want to identity how non-ascii characters are getting into your data upstream but the easy fix is to just delete them:

```
clean_string = "absr\357\277\275/xyz".gsub("\357\277\275","")
  #=> "absr/xyz"
```

Comment: Josh. It's not a matter of removing them from the stream, they actually should be in the database. I simple need a way to identify and remove them. Your solution is fine, but only works in one specific case. I updated my question to say that the above is a *sample* of the non-ASCII values in my database. What I need is a generic approach, whereas this is a specific one.